# Not able to call the callback function of Meteor server side function

Tags: javascript, meteor, request

I'm trying to get a payment gateway up in my Meteor application. I'm getting the redirect url using a `request.post` but I'm not able to callback.

The function returns some data prematurely but it does not return any data from inside the `request.post` callback function to the callback function in the client from where I'm calling this from.

** I also tried `future`, but it gives me a `future.result` not found error

```
pay: function(id)
  {
    var pay_cart = scart.findOne({ _id: id } );
    var pay_user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: pay_cart.user_id } );
    var user_name = pay_user.profile.name;
    var user_email = pay_user.services[Object.keys(pay_user.services)[0]].email;
    var amount = pay_cart.totalPrice.toString();
    var purpose = 'Trn #'+id;
    purpose = purpose.toString();

    var headers = { 'X-Api-Key': 'key-value', 'X-Auth-Token': 'token-value'}
    var payload = {
      purpose: purpose,
      amount: amount,
      phone: '',
      buyer_name: user_name,
      redirect_url: 'http://www.example.com/redirect/'}


    request.post('https://www.instamojo.com/api/1.1/payment-requests/', {form: payload,  headers: headers}, function(error, response, body) {
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 201) {
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(body.longurl);
        //I'm trying to return this longurl
        return body.longurl;
      }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that Meteor doesn't wait until your post request is done. But Meteor does support the new await/async syntax and there is a request-promise package, so the post request returns a promise instead of passing a callback.